# How to change part of an image when it is hovered?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I want to change part of an image when it is hovered.

I have defined a map for the image with 2 areas (circle).

For the first one, I tried to change the src of the image when the circle is hovered via onmouseover on the area. But it blinks on Firefox so it does not seem to work.

For the second one, I let an image appear on top of the other image. It works fine on Firefox (unless I add a tooltip with onmousemove, then it also blinks non stop).

It does not seem to work in either cases on Edge. It's not even getting into the page_bar_mousehover(...) function. I don't understand why, as map and area seem supported.

How to make this work and cross-browser compatible?

```js
function page_bar_mousehover(item) {
    switch (item) {
        case "tooltips_choices":
            document.getElementById('page_bottom_right_bar').src = "./resources/page_bottom_right_bar_hover_tooltips.png";
            break;
        case "hexes_choices":
            if (document.getElementById('page_bottom_right_bar_hover_hexes_img').style != "") {
                document.getElementById('page_bottom_right_bar_hover_hexes_img').style = "";
            }
            break;
    }
}

function page_bar_mouseout() {
    document.getElementById('page_bottom_right_bar').src = "https://i.ibb.co/zS1g5jK/page-bottom-right-bar.png";
    document.getElementById('page_bottom_right_bar_hover_tooltips_img').style = "display:none;";
    document.getElementById('page_bottom_right_bar_hover_hexes_img').style = "display:none;";
}
```

```css
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}

#page_bottom_right_bar_hover_hexes_img, #page_bottom_right_bar_hover_tooltips_img {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img id="page_bottom_right_bar" src="https://i.ibb.co/zS1g5jK/page-bottom-right-bar.png" style="position:fixed;right:0;bottom:0;" usemap="#page_bottom_right_bar" />
  <img id="page_bottom_right_bar_hover_hexes_img" src="https://i.ibb.co/Dt8b5Vb/page-bottom-right-bar-hover-hexes.png" usemap="#page_bottom_right_bar" style="display:none;" />
  <img id="page_bottom_right_bar_hover_tooltips_img" src="https://i.ibb.co/5Gm0PTK/page-bottom-right-bar-hover-tooltips.png" usemap="#page_bottom_right_bar" style="display:none;" alt="coucou" />
  <map id="page_bottom_right_bar">
    <area id="page_bottom_right_bar_hover_hexes_area" shape="circle" coords="26,132,21" alt="Tooltips choices" href="#tooltips_choices" onmouseover="page_bar_mousehover('tooltips_choices');" onmouseout="page_bar_mouseout()">
    <area id="page_bottom_right_bar_hover_tooltips_area" shape="circle" coords="26,177,21" alt="Hexes choices" href="#hexes_choices" onmouseover="page_bar_mousehover('hexes_choices');" onmouseout="page_bar_mouseout();;">
  </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is mainly that the `map` element is not applied correctly, it must have `name` attribute so that it can be referenced. For more details, you could refer to this document:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map#attributes

In your example, you only need to modify the `<map>` `id` attribute to `name`, or add the `name` attribute:

```
<map name="page_bottom_right_bar">
```